# Testing localStorage with Jest & React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, jestjs

I am using Jest to test my react app and I have a component that parses some state data from localStorage in the `componentwillmount` method and saves it to it's state.

Like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    let data = [];

    keys.map((key) => {
        if(Date.parse(key) && moment(key).isValid()) {
            let item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            item['date'] = moment(key);
            data.push(item)
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        data: data
    })
}
```

I am using the `jest-localstorage-mock` package to mock localStorage for Jest and whenever I call `localStorage.setItem(KEY, VALUE)` it gets placed in `localStorage.__STORE__`. Here is the test.

```
it('Should get data from localstorage', () => {
    let obj = {
        date: "2017-12-23T17:33:33.265Z",
        obj: {"pain":"3","work":"9","sleep":"8","notes":"notes","pressure":1025
    }};

    localStorage.setItem(obj.date, JSON.stringify(obj.obj));
    expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // PASSES
    const wrapper = shallow(<Main />);
    console.log(localStorage.__STORE__); // LOOKS LIKE IT SHOULD
    console.log(wrapper.state()); // EMPTY! because all the data is placed into localStorage.__STORE__
    expect(localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // FAILS
})
```

How can I make these two work together so I can test retrieving from localStorage

Comment: I upgraded the package so this works.